# User Defaults not loading in a separate window from where they are saved

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

A question similar to this was posted a couple years ago however, the answer seemed very insufficient. I am saving an array of type `Data` to User Defaults. I have thoroughly debugged my code and verified that there is indeed a value being saved into the User Defaults. The problem is that when I segue to a different view controller and attempt to load the values in the other view controller the result comes back empty.

This is how I set the UserDefaults

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(items, forKey: "savedItems")
```

This is how I am attempting to access

```
  geotifications = []
        guard let savedItems = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "savedItems") else { return } //returning here
        for savedItem in savedItems {
            guard let geotification = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: savedItem as! Data) as? Geotification else { continue }
            self.geotifications.append(geotification)
    }
```

I am using Swift 3 and Xcode 8 any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: You used `PreferencesKeys.savedItems` when saving but `"savedItems"` when you retrieve the data, maybe there is a typo somewhere?

Comment: Sorry I was unclear PreferencesKeys.savedItems is a struct wherein I have a constant "savedItems", I'll fix the question accordingly.

Comment: Can you show what exactly is "items"?

Comment: You need to call UserDefaults.standard.synchronize() after set the items.

Comment: @GeneCode no, you don't.

Comment: @Paulw11 Apple doc says you better do it. And I quote: The synchronize() method, which is automatically invoked at periodic intervals, keeps the in-memory cache in sync with a user’s defaults database.

Comment: That's correct; The system automatically invokes `synchronize` periodically. You don't need t do it. userDefaults is a singleton so the in-memory data is all that is needed

Comment: Actually you need to call synchronize it if you use Userdefaults often. What happens in asker question is  possibly exactly that. The value only gets updated in the memory. But not in sandbox. So when he switch to another segue, possibly requiring more memory and the singleton gets dumped, and when you attempt to read, it's not there. It is good practice to manual call synchronize to ensure data is saved. There are many cases where the memory will be freed by iOS or even if app was terminated forcefully. Finally it is up to you.